# Using Ionic with OMBd API?

Tags: ionic-framework

I recently started playing with Ionic and I'm trying to pull data from OMDb API. Seems there is some trouble with CORS and I've read the guide at http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/, tried adding proxyURL but doesn't seem to work or I'm missing something.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
.controller('MovieController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Star+Wars').success(function(data) {
   $scope.movies = data;
 });
}]);
```

And trying to show the movie data here:

```
  <ion-content ng-controller="MovieController" class="has-subheader">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat='item in movies' class="item-left item-text-wrap">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="Photo">
        <h2>{{ item.Title }}</h2>
        <h3>{{ item.Year }}</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

Full code (not much besides this above) here http://play.ionic.io/app/84f6a0092ffe

What am I missing here? Something needs to be changed in my Ionic project or I'm misusing the OMDb API? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got this. Seems that I needed to request the API a bit differently. Here's an updated, working code.

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, HttpService) {
  HttpService.getPost() 
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.post = response;
    })
})

.service('HttpService', function($http) {
  return {
    getPost: function() {
      return $http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Star+Wars')
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log('Get Post', response);
        return response.data;
      });
    }
  }
})
```

This shows only one item. Remove the `ng-repeat` in the view.

EDIT: It's weird. Doesn't always fetch from OMDb Api. It says `Cross-Origin Request Blocked` now.

Comment: Same CORS issue here. Did you find a way to solve? Can't find anything in the docs.